# Create new column based on string values using Pandas

Tags: pandas, string, list

I have a CSV file that's loaded into pandas which has a string of keys(KEY) in one column and a string of values(VAL) in another column.

I need to identify a predetermined string in the KEY column and populate the corresponding value in the VAL column.  I'm OK hard coding the column names because this will eventually end up in a SQL database and there are issues with dynamically adding columns.

There will always be the same number of keys and values, but the keys will vary in name and number.

Is this possible?

Sample Data:

```
tags='1a','2b','3c','4d'
keys="['os','dist','rel','flag']", \
        "['os','dist']", \
        "['os','dist','rel']", \
        "['os','version','rel','flag']"
vals="['linux','centos','9','y']", \
        "['linux','ubuntu']", \
        "['linux','rhel','8']", \
        "['linux','8','.03','y']"
df=pd.DataFrame({'tag':tags,'key':keys,'val':vals})
```

Desired Result

```
os    | dist   | rel | flag | version
linux | centos | 9   | y    | NaN
linux | ubuntu | NaN | NaN  | NaN
linux | rhel   | 8   | NaN  | NaN
linux | NaN    | .03 | y    | 8
```

Answer (score 0):

In your dataframe, these are not lists, but strings. To extract values into lists, quotes are removed `str.replace("'", '')` and in order not to use square brackets, the line is taken from 1 to the last element:
`str[1:-1]` and finally the words are extracted into the list: `split(',')`

A dataframe with nan is created. In List Comprehension, the necessary values are set in the right places by calling the function.

Doc: [str](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html), [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df['val'] = df['val'].str.replace("'", '').str[1:-1].str.split(',')
df['key'] = df['key'].str.replace("'", '').str[1:-1].str.split(',')

arr = ['os', 'dist', 'rel', 'flag', 'version']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.full((len(df), len(arr)), np.nan), columns=arr)
df1 = df1.astype(str)

def f(x):
    df1.loc[x, df.loc[x, 'key']] = df.loc[x, 'val']


[f(i) for i in range(len(df))]

#uncomment the line below if you need numeric values
#df1[['rel', 'version']] = df1[['rel', 'version']].astype('float')

print(df1)
```

Output

```
      os    dist  rel flag version
0  linux  centos    9    y     nan
1  linux  ubuntu  nan  nan     nan
2  linux    rhel    8  nan     nan
3  linux     nan  .03    y       8
```